# Python mysqldb stops working after trying to connect to DB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

I'm trying to connect to a external database but after trying to connect to the database, the whole script stops running. i'm trying to run it on a Raspberry PI 3. So after the attempt to connect to the database, it stops working. the test print does show up but the second one does not.

Script:

```
import MySQLdb

HOST = "host"
PORT = 3306
USER = "user"
PASS = "pass"
DATABASE = "databasename"


print("test")
db =  MySQLdb.connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE)
print("test2")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Persoon")

data = cursor.fetchone()
print "database version :%s"% data

db.close()
```

Comment: how long have you waited? and for `HOST = "host"` it's usually `HOST = "localhost"` so are you sure of that along with the other credentials?

Comment: @Hamoudaq i just put HOST there because i don't think it's smart to just throw my credentials on the internet, but after HOST theres a IP of a server i host my database on. it's not local

Comment: then, how long have you waited?

Comment: @Hamoudaq Quite a while, but i got it fixed now. it apparantly was a issue with the host my database runs on. they had to whitelist the ip i work on. now i'm getting a error when i try to insert stuff. but i'll make a different question for that. thanks for the answer